# How to determine the value of early_stopping_patience in HuggingFace's Seq2SeqTrainer EarlyStoppingCallback?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

In my `Seq2SeqTrainer`, I use `EarlyStoppingCallback` to stop the training process when the criteria has been met.

```
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model = model,
    args = training_args,
    train_dataset = train_set,
    eval_dataset = eval_set,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,
    data_collator = data_collator,
    compute_metrics = compute_metrics,
    callbacks = [EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=1)]
)
```

Currently, I am using the default value `1` in the `early_stopping_patience`, but how can I determine which value I should use? The [official documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/callback#transformers.EarlyStoppingCallback) doesn't say much.

> early_stopping_patience (int) — Use with `metric_for_best_model` to stop training when the specified metric worsens for `early_stopping_patience` evaluation calls.

Also, could I use *Epoch* instead of *Step* in `evaluation_strategy` with this `EarlyStoppingCallback()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Early stopping patience dictates how much you're willing to wait for your model to improve before stopping training: it is a tradeoff between training time and performance (as in getting a good metric).

Setting a patience of 1 is generally not a good idea as your metric can locally worsen before improving again. You could set a patience of 3 if it takes a lot of time between two evalautions, 5 if they are more frequent, and even more if you can afford the compute time.

For your second question, this callback is compatible with `evaluation_strategy=epoch` (it is actually the setting I've seen the most in the past).